# CSS: How to make a responsive grid without a framework

Tags: html, css

Let's say i have the following HTML

```
<div class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Checkbox</label>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Checkbox with longer text</label>
</div>
<div class="option">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Cbox</label>
</div>
etc...
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q63f3/)

I would like to display these divs in a table-like grid. It has to be responsive, and all columns should have the same width.

For example, when the parent has a 1000px width, and the div with the biggest width is 300px, I want to display 3 columns with a width of 300px each. When the parent has a 600px width, and the div with the biggest width is 300px, i want to display 2 columns width a width of 300px each. And so on.

Please note that the width of these divs can change, as the contents are retrieved from a database.

I read about frameworks that could do this, but I don't need some fancy framework for just this small part of my website.

How would you do this?

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Nothing yet because i don't know how to start. I thought maybe someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: I would suggest [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=How+to+make+your+own+responsive+grid) is your friend here.

Comment: Have a look at `CSS media queries` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @RobinvdA -  if you "don't know how to start"... that's exactly what a framework is for. Try a couple out, see how they are constructed and what you can learn from them. Then, if nothing is fit for task (there are a wide variety out there, from fully styled behemoths like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to very lightweight things like [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)) take what you've learned and roll your own grid.

Comment: I know how to make a responsive design (my website is responsive), however it's just this grid thing i don't get. @CherryFlavourPez Problem with most framework is they use widths. Because the contents are retrieved from a database i prefer not to use widths (unless necessary)

Comment: @RobinvdA - I'm clearly missing something. You don't want to use widths? How do you propose creating any sort of grid without defining the widths of your grid items (even if that's as a percentage or using ems)? A responsive grid will change the widths according to the viewport, but they're still always being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just use widths. In case anyone is interested:

```
.option{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q63f3/3/)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create responsive layout. Few things to consider

- `DIV` is a block level element, for responsiveness, you've to make it
  `inline-block`.
- Give all the width and height in percentage, so that it'll adjust automatically with the screen size changes.
- Any fixed width or height should be given to the parent.

See the following fiddle, you can try resizing your browser to see the responsiveness.

http://jsfiddle.net/yKA8a/embedded/result/

Now for variable number of grids. You need media queries. See following fiddle for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/yKA8a/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

You wanna know how to start with responsive web design ?

Read "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte, as we can't teach you all about designing and coding a responsive website :)